# Transforming DataFrame Rows Into Lists of Column Name and Value Combinations Efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, vectorization

I'm working on formatting my Pandas DataFrame into a required format for a machine learning model.

One of the most frustrating tasks in the preprocessing step is transforming DataFrame rows into lists of column name and value combinations efficiently

an example of two rows in my DataFrame looks something like this:

```
index | userID | col1 | col2 | col3 ... col10000
0        123      0      1      0          1
1        456      1      1      0          0
```

the required format is a list of tuples, where the first value is the userID and the second value is a list that contains a combination of the rest of the column names with their values, e.g:

```
[(123, ['col1:0', 'col2:1', 'col3:0',...., 'col10000:1'])
,(456, ['col1:1', 'col2:1', 'col3:0',...., 'col10000:0'])]
```

I've already tried parallelizing apply but the apply method is still very slow and the parallelization causes memory problems.
The Apply method tried:

```
def add_features(row):
    return ((int(row.iloc[0]),(",".join(["%s:%s"%(x,y) for x,y in row[row.index[1:]].items()]).split(",")))) 
def apply_add_features(df):
    df['features_formatted'] = df.apply(add_features, axis=1)
    return df['features_formatted']
apply_add_features(df)
```

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

you can just do so to your dataframe, notice that i first transform the dataframe to python dictionaties.., which can be more efficient to change the shape, (let me know if the memory issue is solved):
example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userID':np.arange(0,100,10),'a':np.arange(10),'b':np.arange(10)})

 userID a  b
0   0   0  0
1  10   1  1
2  20   2  2
3  30   3  3
4  40   4  4
5  50   5  5
6  60   6  6
7  70   7  7
8  80   8  8
9  90   9  9
```

code to get your result:

```
df = df.set_index('userID')
data =[(k,[f"{k2}:{v}" for k2,v in d.items()]) for k,d in df.to_dict('index').items()]
>>> data
[(0, ['a:0', 'b:0']),
 (10, ['a:1', 'b:1']),
 (20, ['a:2', 'b:2']),
 (30, ['a:3', 'b:3']),
 (40, ['a:4', 'b:4']),
 (50, ['a:5', 'b:5']),
 (60, ['a:6', 'b:6']),
 (70, ['a:7', 'b:7']),
 (80, ['a:8', 'b:8']),
 (90, ['a:9', 'b:9'])]
```

Comment: Hey, Tried your code. Problem is the performance is slow (takes over 5 minutes for less than 60k users, and there will be more than 600k users)

Comment: Can you tell what lines of code is the most consuming? Are you sure that the data isnt large enough to look for orher solutions? How many rows? How many columns? Try to timeit or to use line profiler